# How to schedule a shell command to run in VM instance on GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

I am wanting to schedule a shell command within a VM instance to run on a weekly basis.

How it would work:

- Once a week, Cloud Scheduler invokes pub sub trigger
- Pub sub then pushes message to VM instance's HTTP endpoint
- This in turn causes the shell command to run

I have no problem with steps one and two but I am struggling with how to get the shell command to execute.

One thing I have considered is downloading Python to the VM instance and then creating a Python script that runs an os system command.

```
import os
cmd = "some command"
os.system(cmd)
```

But again though my problem is how do I get the HTTP POST request to cause the Python script to run?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it differently:

- Cloud Scheduler calls a Cloud Function (or Cloud Run)
- The Cloud Function starts an [instance with a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that runs the batch process, and shuts down.

If you need to pass arguments to the script, you can do it using instance metadata when you create the instance (or while it is already running).

Answer (score 0):

I have another cron based approach.

1. Setup VM with shell script
2. Schedule Start/Stop ie 'INSTANCE SCHEDULES' (if required)
3. configure cron job

```
0 9 * * MON /path/to/script/script.sh > /path/to/logs/data_refresh_`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.log
```

(Above job would run every Mon at 0900 hours)